# Change element style after .get() success

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to JS. I'm trying to change button's background-color after .get() success.

Here is example: http://jsfiddle.net/csTpG/95/

What's wrong with my code?

---

```
$('.add').click(function() {
    var productID = $(this).attr('name');
    $.get('/',{item_id : productID}, function() {
        $(this).addClass('clicked');
    });
    return false;
});
```

---

```
<button class="add">click me</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your button has no `name` attribute.

Aside from that, reference the clicked element outside the `$.get` callback to use it in the callback:

```
$('.add').click(function() {
    var productID = $(this).attr('name');
      // keep a reference to the element in this scope
    var self = this;
    $.get('/',{item_id : productID}, function() {
            // use the reference in the callback
        $(self).addClass('clicked');
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `$.get` callback, `this` is not your element.  You need save a reference to `this` first.

```
$('.add').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
    productID = $this.attr('name');
    $.get('/',{item_id : productID}, function() {
        $this.addClass('clicked');
    });
    return false;
});
```